# Using AWK to round E+06 and column calculations

Tags: shell, awk, rounding

I am using the code below to do some calculations. I am trying to round my data to nearest whole number without any decimals or E+06. I have provided sample output. I appreciate any help. I have tried to implement *printf "%.0f"* into my command but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
awk '{$2= ($3)*0.25 -2500; $3= ($3)*0.25 +2500 ; print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3 ;}' file.bed> temp
```

**Sample output**

```
Scaf1 7.74271e+06 7.74771e+06
Scaf2 8.21606e+06 8.22106e+06
Scaf3 6291789 629678
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%.0f` : meaning output will have no precision, meaning rounded up.

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat f
Scaf1 7.74271e+06 7.74771e+06
Scaf2 8.21606e+06 8.22106e+06
Scaf3 6291789 629678

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk '{printf ("%s %.0f %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3)}' f
Scaf1 7742710 7747710
Scaf2 8216060 8221060
Scaf3 6291789 629678
```